# Using C++ Classes in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

How can I use a C++ class in Delphi? I am trying to use it through an abstract class. However it doesn't work as expected I get weird numbers from `Age();`.

**Delphi:**

```
program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  IPerson = class
    function Age(): Integer; overload; virtual; stdcall; abstract;
    procedure Age(const Value: Integer); overload; virtual; stdcall; abstract;
  end;

const
  DLL = 'Interface.DLL';

procedure FreePerson(const Person: IPerson); external DLL;
function CreatePerson(): IPerson; external DLL;

var
  Person: IPerson;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Person := CreatePerson;
  Person.Age(10);
  I := Person.Age(); // I is not 10?

end.
```

**C++:**

```
extern "C" class _declspec(dllexport) IPerson
{
    virtual void Age(const int Value) = 0;
    virtual int Age() = 0;
};


class Person: public IPerson
{
private:
    int FAge;
public:
    void Age(const int Value){FAge = Value;};
    int Age(){return FAge;};
    Person(){ FAge = 0; };
    ~Person(){};
};


extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) IPerson* CreatePerson()
{
    return new Person;
}

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void FreePerson(Person** obj)
{
    delete obj;
}
```

Comment: It looks a little bit odd using prefix `I` for a normal class. Everyone would expect an interface. And an interface is that what you should use for that

Comment: I don't see `__stdcall` in your C++ code. If you are using only virtual methods and same calling convention on both sides I believe it should work.

Comment: @user It would only ever work so long as the compilers happened to lay out the VMT in an identical way. No reason to expect that. That the caller specified the methods in different orders won't help.

Comment: Rudy Velthuis wrote a good article about that: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html

Comment: I see no reason why it should't work with GCC/FPC. VMT format is identical everywhere though it is never stated explicitely

Comment: @user On the C++ side that is true. Because that's how COM is implemented. But why should Delphi classes be the same?

Comment: @John Why are you trying to reinvent COM?

Comment: No they are not refcounted. Not sure about the latest MACOS/IOS compilers though.

Comment: @user It's the Clang based mobile compilers that use ARC

Comment: OK, then the OP trick is clean. He should be very careful with vtable though, ex I don't know what will happen if he will declare virtual destructor on C++ side - I believe the VMT correspondence will be broken.

Comment: I don't quite understand you. I believe you need `__stdcall` in your C++ export declarations. Just be careful and no haste.

Comment: Debugger shows `()` because `IPerson` has no data members.

Comment: No. A pure abstract class has no data members. You clearly don't want to use COM, so good luck!

Comment: If you mean GCC not on Windows - I don't know. I used GCC on Windows for kinda reversed task - to wrap Delphi interface in C++ class, and it worked ok.

Comment: When are you going to realise that you can't do this? Use COM or flatten the interface.

Answer (score 5):

You can't interop with C++ classes from Delphi. In fact, you can only reasonably do it from C++ if you use the same compiler and runtime.

What you need to do, to interop between C++ and Delphi, is to expose your C++ classes using COM. If COM is not an option then flattening the class is the alternative. Rudy Velthuis covers these options here: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html

Comment: Thanks for the mention! The flattening is easier from the C(++) side, the COm option is easier for the Delphi side.