# Using C++ Builder classes in Delphi

Tags: delphi, c++builder

Using RAD Studio 10, from Delphi unit I need to instance forms and data modules written in C++ Builder, in order to manage their public data and call their function.
As ".hpp" files generated by Delphi can be included into C++ Builder units, what is the way to include into Delphi forms the ".h" headers developed in C++ Builder?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's quite so easy in that direction

Comment: So, using C++ Builder units/classes in Delphi is impossibile?

Comment: You can include delphi units into C++ Builder, but the other way is more complex. See [Using C++ Classes in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666919/using-c-classes-in-delphi) and also the link to [rudy's article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html).

Comment: I don't think you can do it directly in the same way. You have to use standard interop techniques.

Comment: I'll do a try. Thanks all!